# GRASS GIS - 'cat' directory showing 0 categories for reclassified DEM?

Tags: arcmap, grass-gis, import, reclassify

I am trying to use an online model (Titan2D) which requires a material map (a DEM that has been reclassified so that each group can be assigned a value of constant bed friction angle once it has been uploaded into the model) which must be in a GRASS GIS format, however, I'm having problems... When I upload the material map the model says that there are no 'material names' which are created in the 'cat' folder during the GRASS GIS part. So I think that must be where I'm going wrong?

Within ArcMap, I have reclassified a DEM so that ranges of elevation have been assigned an integer value. I have ended up with the DEM split into 11 groups. 
Next, I have used the 'raster to ASCII' tool and imported the new text file into GRASS GIS using the 'r.in.gdal' option. 
Next, I go into the 'cat' directory and edit the file so that each of my reclassified groups has a material name, however, to begin with, the file says that there are no categories...

'# 0 categories

0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00'

Could this indicate that the reclassified groups I previously made haven't been picked up? 
I've tried editing this file so it reads as:
'# 0 categories
Vector map: Slope

0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
1:SlopeA
2:SlopeB
3:SlopeC
4:SlopeD
5:SlopeE
6:SlopeF
7:SlopeG
8:SlopeH
9:SlopeI
10:SlopeJ
11:SlopeK'

But this is what causes me the error.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know anything about Titan2d, b ut I scimmed thru the user manual. It seems that you can prepare a materials map (raster) in GRASS then point the program to that map in the GRASS folder structure. You would prepare the materials map by running `r.reclass` on your DEM. (No need for ArcGIS in the middle). The reclass map will have the needed entries in `cats`, `cellhd` etc. You do not create these folders or files manually.

Comment: Please check if your https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Computational_region is set correctly (g.region command)